# android:How to set images in imageview using counter?

Tags: android

I am having set of 4 images. I need to place them in the Image View using counter.I want to play animation using counter. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example [Frame by Frame XML Animation with Google Android](http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35)

Comment: hello jett... I need to do it with counter... not frame by frame animation.